# Is there a cleaner way to use Optional here without returning "NA" in three places?

Tags: java, option-type

```
    public String getSanitisedMessage() {

        Throwable rootCause = context.getRootCauseException();
        if(rootCause != null) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(rootCause.getMessage())
                    .map(message -> Stream.of(
                            // clean message substrings we want to find
                            "Connection timed out",
                            "Connection reset",
                            "Connection was lost",
                            "FTP Fails"
                    ).filter(subString -> message
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .contains(subString.toLowerCase())
                    ).findFirst().orElse("NA")
                    ).orElse("NA");
        } else return "NA";

    }
```

The objective is to check the `Throwable`'s message for substrings and if found then return the substring, otherwise return `NA`.
Both `context.getRootCauseException()` and the `Throwable.getMessage()` calls could return `null`.

Comment: I hope it is (and look forward to reading answers), though with the initial `if` you may be stuck with at least two. I'd at least mitigate by putting `final String defaultResult = "NA";` at the top and using it in the two/three places.

Comment: Starting from java9 Optional can yield a stream thus it can be  flatmapped, check https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-optional/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way is to use `flatMap` with `findFirst` instead of `map` as:

```
// method argument is just for the sake of an example and clarification here 
public String getSanitisedMessage(Throwable rootCause, Set<String> primaryCauses) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(rootCause)
            .map(Throwable::getMessage)
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .flatMap(message -> primaryCauses.stream()
                    .map(String::toLowerCase)
                    .filter(message::contains)
                    .findFirst())
            .orElse("NA");
}
```

Or a ternary operator could also be used  to represent it as:

```
return rootCause == null || rootCause.getMessage() == null ? "NA" :
        primaryCauses.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).filter(subString -> rootCause.getMessage()
                .toLowerCase().contains(subString)).findFirst().orElse("NA");
```

Answer (score 0):

Imo you should throw an exception here, and handling it properly ( it seems you're going to check the String later ).
If you want to stick this way, you could either add a default value to your context.getMessage() ( assuming that's a custom class implementing Context ), and return its value.

Otherwise, you could also do the following :

```
 Throwable rootCause = context.getRootCauseException();
    if (rootCause != null) {
        return Stream.of("Connection timed out",
                "Connection reset",
                "Connection was lost",
                "FTP Fails")
                     .filter(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(rootCause.getMessage()))
                     .findFirst()
                     .orElse("NA");
    }
    return "NA";
 }
```

Comment: In my specific case here I don't want to throw an exception because the function is actually being called from an MVEL expression, don't ask... :o)